# jquery datatable missing headers

Tags: jquery, datatables

JSP page

```
<table id="popcostTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Region Name</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>                        
</table>
```

JS code used for generating the table

```
   UI.node.popupcostTable = $('#popcostTable');       
    dataSrc=[["NAM","1"],["EMEA","2"]];
UI.node.popupcostTable.DataTable({
          "data":dataSrc,
          "paging":   false,
           "info":     false,
           "ordering": false,
           "filter" : false,
           "Processing": true,
           "destroy": true,
           "aoColumnDefs" : [{
                "aTargets" : [1], // Column to target
                "mRender" : function(data, type, full) {
                    return FRUtil.currencyFormat(data);
                }
            }   
            ],
           "bAutoWidth": true
            });         
};
```

not showing the "Region name" and "Cost" in the table header and no error report

Comment: FRUtil  is the function we used for format the column, not related with the datatable columns missing

Comment: Please add clarifications directly to your question. Also consider providing a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Adding the `jquery` tag (at a minimum) may increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: see if its hidden by css

Comment: can you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself, I reset the table during the js code with 
`UI.node.popupcostTable.html(''),` 
when create the data table, that's why missing the headers.